# Moving Squares Freeze Tag

Tags: java

For my project we have to have four square moving and bouncing off the sides and when it hits a side it changes color. When you click on one of the squares it freezes and turns red. So far i have the four squares and when I click them it says it freezes them. However, I'm not positive how to get them to move and bounce off the sides. Below is the code i have written so far.

MAIN:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StationarySquare[] squares = new StationarySquare[4];
        Random rng = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
            squares[i] = new StationarySquare(rng.nextDouble(), rng.nextDouble());
        }

        while (true) {
            StdDraw.clear();

            int count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
                squares[i].draw();

                if (StdDraw.mousePressed()
                        && squares[i].containsPoint(StdDraw.mouseX(), StdDraw.mouseY())) {
                    squares[i].freeze();
                }

                if (squares[i].isFrozen()) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            StdDraw.text(0.5, 0.5, "Frozen: " + count);

            StdDraw.show(25);
        }
    }
}
```

My other class

```
import java.util.Random;

public class StationarySquare {
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double halfLength;
    private int red;
    private int green;
    private int blue;
    private boolean isFrozen;

    public StationarySquare(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        halfLength = 0.1;
        isFrozen = false;
        randomColor();
    }

    public void draw() {
        if (isFrozen) {
            StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.RED);
        } else {
            StdDraw.setPenColor(red, green, blue);
        }
        StdDraw.filledSquare(x, y, halfLength);
    }

    public void randomColor() {
        Random rng = new Random();

        red = rng.nextInt(256);
        green = rng.nextInt(256);
        blue = rng.nextInt(256);
    }

    public void freeze() {
        isFrozen = true;
    }

    public boolean containsPoint(double a, double b) {
        return a > x - halfLength &&
                a < x + halfLength &&
                b > y - halfLength &&
                b < y + halfLength;
    }

    public boolean isFrozen() {
        return isFrozen;
    }
}
```

Comment: depends in which way you want them to move, as in horizontally, vertically or randomly. Anyway the clue is obviously you can achieve that using the 'x' and 'y' fields

Comment: Each rect needs direction variables for x and y. Each time you refresh the display, change the rects x and y by these values. (They can be negative or positive).

Comment: I want them to move randomly around the screen. I just dont know how to get that. I know I have to add velocity and stuff i just dont know which class or where to put it

Comment: I was working on the same project, you can see my solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587492/freeze-moving-rectangles/42587949?noredirect=1#comment72391754_42587949